# Owlcarousel2 functions does not work with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a gem owlcarousel: https://github.com/SirJls/owlcarousel2-rails

I made the inclusions as read: In the .js file

```
//= require owlcarousel2/owl.carousel
```

In the .scss file:

```
@import 'owlcarousel2/owl.carousel';
@import 'owlcarousel2/owl.theme.default';
```

In the .html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'myarquive.js'%>
```

The .js file includes the call to the owlcarousel functions

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      items:1,
      nav:true,
      autoplay:true,
     });
    })
```

In the .html.erb arquive I set up the next structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x500?text=Slider+A"/>
      <div class="item-caption">
        <h3>Slider A Caption</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x500?text=Slider+B"/>
      <div class="item-caption">
        <h3>Slider B Caption</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1200x500?text=Slider+C"/>
      <div class="item-caption">
        <h3>Slider C Caption</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

In my .scss:

```
.owl-carousel{
  position: relative;
}

.owl-carousel .item{
  height: 500px;
}

.owl-carousel .item img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-carousel .item .item-caption{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  color: #337ab7;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The owlcarousel is activated and is working but the items that call the specific functions are not activating such as nav and autoplay. They do not work, how can I do it work and activate owlcarousel items?

The Item items are working normally and nav and autoplay do not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){...
```

instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

This is because your document should be ready when turbonliks is ready, for later run your js.

Comment: I tested with addEventListener as mentioned, but the slide did not load either. With the reader it loads and works. Even some items like items, loop and margin I tested and are working, now items like nav, autoplay and autoplayTimeout do not work.

Comment: I just used it as function too:
`$(function() {...`
The slide loaded but the nav, autoplay, and autoplayTimeout items still did not work.

Comment: I checked the project more, and it is not using turbolinks and also does not own the gem turbolinks.